# WAN connectivity failure every 5 minutes on Technicolor router

Tags: network, wifi, airport, router

Starting recently, my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.2 loses its Internet connection every five minutes or so.

My router, a Technicolor TC8717T (don't ask, it's the free one from my ISP) provides two wifi networks:

- TC8717T88 (2.4 GHz)
- TC8717T88-5G (5 GHz)

Regardless of which wifi network I'm connected to, the Internet connection will die after about five minutes. The computer will remain connected to the wifi network, at full signal strength, but I'll be unable to browse to any websites or do anything over the Internet.

When this happens, Network Diagnostics will report that the connection to my ISP is failing, and Wireless Diagnostics will report a "WAN Connectivity Failure" and advise that I restart my router.

At this point, if I do any of the following...

- Switch to the other network (from 2.4 GHz to 5 GHz or vice versa)
- Disconnect from and reconnect to the same network
- Turn my wifi off and back on
- Restart my router

...the Internet connection will be restored, but only for another five minutes or so, until it fails again in the same fashion.

What could be causing this, and is there anything else I can try?

---

Update: two other pieces of info that I've discovered:

- When the connection drops, other devices on the same wifi network remain connected. For example, my Apple TV will continue to stream a show, even though the MacBook Pro has lost the connection
- ...but at the same time, my MacBook Pro only exhibits this issue on my home wifi network. For example, on my office wifi, the connection is always stable

---

Here's a screenshot of my network settings:

[image: Network Settings]

Comment: This looks a lot like a traditionnal problem with the cursed `Automatic` location (which in fact is a network configuration). Could you include a screen capture of your `System Preferences > Network`?

Comment: Please add: the make of your wireless router, and the names of your 2 wireless networks.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, what's the problem with the Automatic location? That's how mine is set as you can see, but I don't know what the alternative is...

Comment: Please check the idle timeout settings in your router

Comment: The alternative to `Automatic` location is a dedicated location with just the network configuration which should work at home. You can create it from the drop down menu `System Preferences > Network > Location: > Edit Locations...`, starting by a duplicate of the `Automatic` one and removing everything which will cause MacOS X to switch when signal varies (which is always the case on wireless network).

Comment: Do you have neighbour wireless networks?

Comment: What are the security setting of each  of your network connections (on your TC8717T router)?

Comment: @klanomath: there is no such thing as an idle timeout or an ARP timeout tuning on this router (at least accessible through its web admin interface).

Comment: Please install iStumbler and run it from the exact place where you have this 5 min disconnection.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, I have iStumbler running, but what am I supposed to be looking for when the connection drops?

Comment: You should sort your networks by S/N ratio decreasing order. You should look at any order change. On this change, your Mac will have to make a connection configuration switch. My experience is that this switch leads to link layer loops, ARP, IP or DNS drops.

Comment: You might include a screen capture of the top of the screen of iStumbler sorted by S/N ration decreasing order.

Comment: @daGUY Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @RafaelOliveira yes, replace the router! 

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to turn off the 2.4 GHz wireless network named TC8717T88 on your router. Then your `Automatic` location will stop magically switching from one to the other wireless networks, thus having the valid IP for the other network (which doesn't fit the DHCP lease of the actual one).

You will be able to change this from a perfectly connected computer (ideally through Ethernet). Open your web browser, and connect to your TC8717T router with:

http://192.168.0.1

```
login:          admin
password:       password
```

goto:

```
Gateway > Connection > WiFi
```

click:

```
EDIT
```

Configure as disabled the "Private WiFi Network Configuration (2.4 GHz)".
Configure on Manual channel choice the "Private WiFi Network Configuration (5 Ghz)".

I made the hypothesis (which is quite often the case) that your 2.4 GHz
is overloaded and sometimes subject to access failure due to interfering neighbours network. Then by forcing your connexion on 5 GHz and a given channel you will get a stable one, without anymore dynamic IP renewal.

Comment: Switching between different frequencies (or channels) shouldn't affect neither DHCP nor the validity of the IP! IEEE 802.11 is OSI 1/2! Switching between 2.4 and 5 GHz using my router is almost seamless: maybe some IP packets get lost; but they will be retransmitted.

Comment: Because (if I guess right) you defined these 2 channels use as **one** network on your router, with one **name** and hidden **one** DHCP range of IP addresses.

Comment: I don't think this is it, because I have the same problem when I'm connected to the 5 GHz network too. It's not switching back and forth between the 2.4 GHz and the 5 GHz, it's just failing after a few minutes on either one. They're set up as two different networks with two different names, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: To try to understand your problem, is it working fine with **only** the 5GHz network?

Comment: No, it's not – I disabled the 2.4 GHz network and I still have the same problem on the 5 GHz network (had to disconnect and reconnect to post this very comment).

Comment: However your wireless problem will stay unsolvable in this setting since typically 802.11b/g and 802.11a/n/ac have completely different behaviour in term of range and throughput. The cursed case is when you are just on the border of the correct range for one and within the other. You will be in a continuously switching network configuration. -------- Imagine yourself reading a book within an environment flashing between red and blue lights every 5 minutes.

Comment: Understood, but that doesn't seem to be the case here since I still have the problem with only the 5 GHz network enabled. Also, I've had this same router/setup for almost a year and had no issues like this until last month when I posted my question. Starting to wonder if the router itself is flaking out...